# How to exclude a dependency from final artifact (jar) but need to be used when compile and run unit test in gradle

Tags: gradle

I have a dependency need to be used when compile or run unit test for that project, but I don't want to include it inside my final artifact (a jar file) because I will specify this dependency in class path when using "java xx.jar" command to run it. Below is my current configuration in build.gradle.

configurations {
    providedRuntime
    runtime.exclude module:'dependencyA'
}

dependencies {
    compile ('groupA:dependencyA:versionX')
}

The above setting can ensure dependencyA functions when compile the project, and also exclude dependencyA from the final jar file. But when run unit test, it can't find dependencyA, since it gets excluded.
How can I include dependencyA for unit test running, and in the meanwhile, exclude dependencyA from the final jar file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpler solution is to do the following:

```
dependencies {
    // Makes the dependency appear _only_ on compileClasspath
    compileOnly('groupA:dependencyA:versionX')
    // Makes the dependency appear _only_ on testRuntimeClasspath
    testRuntimeOnly('groupA:dependencyA:versionX')
}
```

See [the documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/5.2.1/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_plugin_and_dependency_management) for an explanation on the different configurations available through the `java` plugin